# Compact way to build a String starting at null using +=

Tags: java

I would like to use the following compact way to build a `String`:

```
String attributes = null;
for (Map.Entry<String, String> kvp : attrs.entrySet())
  attributes += (kvp.getKey() + "='" + kvp.getValue() +"' ");
```

but the result is a String which reads: `nullattr1='val1' attr2='val2' attr3='val3'`. I presume that this is happening as a result of performing a `+=` operation on a `String` whose current value is null. Is there no compact way to do this without having to check if `attributes` is null each time through the loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this for initializing the `String` at the beginning of the code:

```
String attributes = "";
```

Answer (score 7):

```
String attributes = "";
```

would allow that, and be fine for small maps of 5 or 20 values. For larger maps, StringBuilder or ~Buffer is the way to go:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer (estimatedSize);
for (X x: xx) 
     sb.append (foo).append (bar).append (baz);
String attributes = sb.toString ();
```

Answer (score 3):

**`null` is not an empty string**.

You should start with `""` instead of `null`:

```
String attributes = "";
...
```

If the `'...'` are not necessary, the most compact way would be to do

```
String attributes = "";
for (Map.Entry<String, String> kvp : attrs.entrySet())
  attributes += kvp + " ";
```

If you have many values, it is also recommended to use `StringBuilder` instead of just `String`:

```
StringBuilder attributes = new StringBuilder();
for (Map.Entry<String, String> kvp : attrs.entrySet())
    attributes.append(kvp.getKey())
              .append("='")
              .append(kvp.getValue())
              .append("' ");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String attributes = "";
for (Map.Entry kvp : attrs.entrySet())
  attributes += (kvp.getKey() + "='" + kvp.getValue() +"' ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of saying `String attributes = null;`, just say `String attributes = "";`

If you're going to be adding a lot of strings, you might want to look into StringBuilder, because that internally avoids reallocating memory every time you add something new to the end, which += does.

Comment: This is Java, not C++. You mean StringBuilder.

Comment: Thank you, my mind must have slipped about which section this question was in.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone else is right, you can just set your `String` to the empty string at the start, but if you are building a string from a lot of data, might want to use a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) object, which is designed for string building.

```
public String getString(Map<String, String> attrs)  {
    StringBuilder bldr = new StringBuilder();
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> kvp : attrs.entrySet()) {
        bldr.append(String.format("'%s'='%s' ", kvp.getKey(), kvp.getValue()));
    }
    return bldr.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialise `attributes` as:

```
String attributes = "";
```

**Edited**

Comment: Completely unnecessary. What do you think the `valueOf`will do for a.. well string?

Comment: Class String can reuse objects if you use valueOf rather than explicitly creating a new String object. I personally do this way and stack with it - whether completely unessary or neccesary it is a matter of design choice and love to do it this way.

Comment: Constant string values are already interned - in fact it's demanded by the JLS. Hence there's only *one* string `""` and using valueOf won't change that fact. As long as you don't use the string constructor it won't have any negative side effects, but it's still completely unnecessary :)

Comment: No but `""` is. There's not even a `valueOf(String)` method, what you actually get is `return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();` and `obj.toString()` is the identity function for strings. valueOf does no interning of any kind, it's only useful if you have some other data like strings..